# Oill pressure fluctuations on 1989 Chevrolet S10

Tags: chevrolet, oil-pressure

I have a 1989 S10 blazer with a 4.3l V6. I was having some overheating issues for the last few weeks . The good folks here helped me diagnose it as a burnt out fan clutch. I thought that the oil pressure will stop jumping and the check gauges light stop lighting up after swapping it with a new one ; but that's not the case.

After the truck has cooled down and I start driving it , the oil pressure gauge and the temperature gauge stays at normal operating levels.

**Observed behavior**

At time abruptly the oil pressure drops to 0 while driving and stats there. When I come to a full stop , I notice the check gauges sign ,lights up because of the low oil pressure.

When I start moving , the oil pressure needle moves enough to not light up the check gauges light.

After a bit , the oil gauge reads normal levels and the. It jumps back to zero .

I've noticed that when I am on the move the check gauges sign don't light up even though the oil pressure gauge reads zero.

During this time the temperature gauge remains well below 50 and it doesn't rise even though the truck is idling.

Comment: Have the oil pressure checked with a test gauge fitted directly to the engine - most decent shops have them. If the oil pressure is really close to zero then the engine won’t last long...

Comment: +1 on @SolarMike, you shouldn't trust the instrument cluster oil gauge much as these can get you faulty readings. The misreading gauges is a common issue with older GM vehicles. Get a real oil pressure gauge connected to the oil pressure port.

Comment: check the dipstick; the gage has nothing to do with the volume of oil . unless you are about empty.